# Failed to get JENKINS current directory in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have used below line to identify the html file. But It returned exception.

```
  def location=${workspace}/report_${BUILD_NUMBER}
  println(location)
  def report=build.getWorkspace().child(location+"/report.html")
```

***Exception Observed:***

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: workspace for
>   class: groovy.lang.Binding    at
>   groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)  at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:224)
>     at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedGetProperty.callStatic(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:230)
>     at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)

Anybody can help me how to get the current workspace and append that value into some string like below:

```
location+"/report.html"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
build.getWorkspace().child("report_${BUILD_NUMBER}/report.html")
```

instead of `report.html` you can define the path relative to workspace directory. it should be without `/` at the beginning.

if you are not sure about directory structure, you can try to list files in workspace directory:

```
build.getWorkspace().list().each{ println it }
```

Comment: I cant directly use absolute path because there is a report folder which appends build number. I would like to try second one but im not sure it will print all the folder and how can i switch to the respective one

Comment: just add report folder name as a relative path. updated the answer.

Comment: How can I get all the report from that directory. like I have report1.html, and report2.html